# XNA Shadow mapping - invalid model?

Tags: xna

I try to use shadow mapping sample from http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/shadow_mapping_1.
When I try to load my model there is an exception in:

```
effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques[techniqueName];
```

in DrawModel method.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll
Additional information: This method does not accept null for this parameter.
```

What can be wrong with my model?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `techniqueName` variable isn't `null`.

I'm betting `effect.Techniques[null]` throws a `System.ArgumentNullException` for the same reason [Dictionary.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does.

Comment: It's not null. techniqueName is "CreateShadowMap". I have no idea what can I do with it.

Comment: I probably should've seen that "occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll".  I got nothin; maybe see if effect.Techniques["CreateShadowMap"] is returning null and setting effect.CurrentTechnique to null.

Comment: Ok. effect.Techniques doesn't contain "CreateShadowMap" and "DrawWithShadowMap". There is only "BasicEffect". So what can I do? I guess it's something with my model. But what? Is it need to be created in some "special way"?

Comment: I believe that you either have to manually define and add the effects yourself, or they are baked into the model data you're working with. Where did you get your model from?

Comment: The first one was from SkinnignSample. The second was created by me. Both of them are not working